# My SELECT statement is not working correctly with form submitted variables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I have a page that receives form data from a submitted form, I wrote a SELECT statement to search my database when the page is loaded (from the form submit) and the POST form variables are created. The problem I'm having is the query returns 0 Results using the $aircraftMake variable but when I enter a static value in place of the variable I get the desired results. I am fairly new to all this so any help would be appreciated. I have listed the code below.

```
    <?php 
$aircraftMake = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['marke']);
$aircraftModel =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['model']);
$engine =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Motorisation']);
?>

</head>

<body>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM QuoteData WHERE aircraftMake = '$aircraftMake'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["aircraftMake"]. "<br>" . $row["aircraftModel"]. "<br>" . $row["engineModel"]. "<br>" . $row["overhauledEngineSteelCylinders"]. "<br>" . $row["overhauledEngineNickelCylinders"]. "<br>" . $row["overhauledEngineNewCylinders"]. "<br>" . $row["individualOverhauledSteelCylinder"]. "<br>" . $row["setOfFourOverhauledSteelCylinders"]. "<br>" . $row["individualOverhauledNickelCylinder"]. "<br>" . $row["setOfFourOverhauledNickelCylinders"]. "<br>" . $row["engineCoreValue"]. "<br>" . $row["note1"]. "<br>" . $row["note2"]. "<br>" . $row["note3"]. "<br>" . $row["OverhaulIncludes"]. "<br>" . "<br>" .  $row["shippingToInclude"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is happening, error, no results? @kailashsharma select statement is valid the double quotes allow the variable to be parsed by the PHP.

Comment: your code looks ok. Plz check your db connection and also print $sql variable and then fire that query in database to check if it is giving output or not.

Comment: Just guessing, but is there a typo here? `$_POST['marke']` Maybe `$_POST['make']` instead?

Comment: No, 'marke' is correct, thanks though :-)

Comment: Ah, I just thought maybe, because it was going into another variable with 'make' in it. Oh well.

Comment: Considering what you've said about how this is working, it seems like the problem might be with your form. Maybe add that code here as well?

Comment: what is correct static value you test with? could you `var_dump($sql)` before `->query($sql)` please?

Comment: OK, for some reason it worked once (without me changing anything in the code, I did however refresh everything), when I go back to the form and submit a different choice the variables appear on my results page but I get "0 results" again. Do I need to reset this every time a form is submitted or something??

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok, are you sure your `$_POST` data is set?

```
<?php
  if(isset($aircraftModel)){
     // code here
  }
```

Comment: You you a 100% thats the name (QuoteData) of you table in the db?

Comment: Yes, when I enter a static value instead of the variable I get proper results, thanks though

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM QuoteData WHERE aircraftMake = '".$aircraftMake."'";
```

Comment: How's this different than OPs query?

Comment: Sorry kailash-sharma that didn't work either. The odd thing is if I put in an aircraft make instead of the variable between the single quotes it pulls the correct data, if I use the $aircraftMake variable I return "0 Results"

Comment: This will produce the same SQL string.

Comment: What happens when you echo the $sql variable? Is it correctly constructed?

Comment: Sorry, here is the echo statement: <?php
echo $airMake, $airModel, $engine
?>

Comment: Sorry again, here it is correctly: <?php
echo $aircraftMake, $aircraftModel, $engine
?>